# Getting network information in Webworks plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

Trying my hands on writing Blackberry Webworks plugins. I want to check the network status while on the "server" side of the cordova plugin. How do I add the network info API `org.apache.cordova.network-information` so it'll be available in my plugin? I get the network-info to work if I use it in an app, but don't know how to make it work at my plugin level.

I tried adding `<dependency id="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />` or

`<feature name="NetworkStatus"> <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" /> </feature>`

in plugin.xml but neither works. Using the `<dependency>` tag will make Webworks automatically include the network-info in the app build and install, but `navigator.connection` is still undefined at the plugin server-side level. Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out. Forget about using another pluging in my plugin.
The only line needed is `window.qnx.webplatform.device.activeConnection`, which is defined whenever there is an active connection and can be used to check connection type.

The network plugin `org.apache.cordova.network-information` is basically using that same call on the server side.